# Communication while editing - revision comment for rollbacks, or even comment thread for edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, revisions-list

I just had a really annoying occurrence of someone editing my question.  Essentially someone changed one word `comprised` -> `composed`.  The edit summary (aka revision comment) of the edit was `comprised != composed`... Now the editor thought he was doing me a favor and correcting my English, but wouldn't you know: I actually meant `comprised`.

Right then and there I rolled it back - not a problem.

At the very least I'd have liked to put "no i meant comprised" in the edit summary for the rollback, but the summary was auto-populated to "rollback to rev x". *(apparently this already exists...)*

---

**But** I still think a full-blown comment thread for edits might be a good idea to facilitate the refinement of questions.  Short of commenting on my original question there is no way to do this right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can currently perform a rollback with an edit summary. If you choose to edit a post, you notice the dropdown at the top? If you select an earlier revision, you can basically submit it without changes, but supply a revision summary.

Check it out in real action with this [screencast](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26426/gracenitpicking.htm) [from Gaming user](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/what-is-rolling-back/1413#1413) [Arda Xi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/56/arda-xi)!

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think a rollback states pretty explicitly, **"No, I meant that!"** and most people will not override a rollback without putting some careful thought into it.